# Dynamic override methods of Python base class

Tags: python, dynamic, overriding, getattr, getattribute

I am given a Python base class that defines an interface which I must implement in a derived class. In the base class, each method is defined as a stub that throws `NotImplementedError`.

There are many such methods and their names are mostly very regular, of the form `<Operation><Type>`. In principle the vast majority could be implemented by dispatching to a single method that takes `"<Operation>"` and `"<Type>"`, parsed from the method name, as arguments. I would like to do something like this to avoid boilerplate. *However, there are a small number of methods that would need an explicit override*.

```
class Base(object):
    ...
    # 'Regular' methods - the majority of the interface
    def CreateObj1(self, arg):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    def DeleteObj1(self, arg):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    # etc.. for a number of such operations
    #       for many type Obj1, Obj2, ...

    # A few methods that don't fit the above pattern
    def SpecialMethod1(self, arg):
        raise NotImplementedError()
    ...

class Derived(Base):
    ...
    def _impl(self, operation_name, object_type, arg):
        # With this I am essentially able to implement
        # all of the 'regular' methods
        ...

    def CreateObj1(self, arg):
        return self._impl('Create', 'Obj1', arg)
    def DeleteObj1(self, arg):
        return self._impl('Delete', 'Obj1', arg)

    def SpecialMethod1(self, arg):
        # This still needs an explicit implementation
        ...
    ...
```

I *could* just implement it as above but I would prefer not to have to write all of the explicit delegators for the 'regular' methods as it adds a place that needs maintenance when the interface is extended.

My first thought was to define a `__getattr__` method, but the problem is that the base stub methods 'win' and `__getattr__` is not called. I *think* I might be able to make it work with `__getattribute__` but I have never needed to use this before and am wary because I understand that one can easily get into a mess by misusing it.

Does `__getattribute__` sound like the correct way to go with this or are there other approaches that I might be missing?

If it is the right approach, are there any particular patterns I could follow to ensure that I use it correctly?

What would be the best way to deal with the small number of methods that cannot be dynamically overridden and which need explicit implementations in the derived class?

Comment: Why don't you just have a single method that takes `operation` and `type` as parameters?

Comment: You should make the base class an Abstract Base Class, that will automate the "not implemented" errors.

Comment: @Barmar the base class is not under my control.

Comment: Edited wording slightly to make this clearer.

Comment: It's hard to answer questions in abstract like this. Please show the actual code you're talking about.

Comment: @Barmar I have sketched out the classes involved.

Comment: @Bob If I understand correctly, you want to only define `_impl` manually on the derived classes and have the other methods (`CreateObj1` etc) have the default implementation (without explicitly writing all that code in each subclass) like you've show in `Derived`?

Comment: @Kedar - yes that's right. Note that I could explore options like generating the code and may even end up doing something like that, but I am curious about the best way to do it completely dynamically using a 'getattr'-type approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a metaclass (handle with care)

```py
class BaseMeta(type):
    def get_default_impl(base_attr, subject="Obj1"):
        # modify this method
        action, _ = base_attr.split(subject)

        def _default(self, arg):
            return self._impl(action, subject, arg)
        return _default

    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs):
        # print("attrs:", attrs, "base:", bases)
        for base in bases:
            for base_attr in dir(base):
                if base_attr.endswith("Obj1"):  # modify this
                    attrs.setdefault(base_attr, mcs.get_default_impl(base_attr))

        def _impl(self, operation_name, object_type, arg):
            raise NotImplementedError()

        attrs.setdefault("_impl", _impl)
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)


class Derived(Base, metaclass=BaseMeta):
    def _impl(self, operation_name, object_type, arg):
        print("got op:{}, obj: {}, arg: {}".format(operation_name, object_type, arg))
```

You will need to modify `if base_attr.endswith("Obj1"):` and `get_default_impl` according to how the methods on the base class are defined. I've worked with the example you've posted.